# Equalizer: what dose each sound bar numbered 60, 230, 910, 3.6k, and 14k. And how do I set to get rid of all background sounds

Tags: noise, background

How do I work thos equalizer with sound bars labeled 60, 230, 910, 3.6k, and 14k and wat dose each one of these bars and numbers mean

Comment: I'm trying to figure out like the meaning of the bars and how to eliminate background noise and her other thing closer or farther away better

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is badly written, ill conceived and doesn't fit this site. This site is for professionals or enthusiasts asking well defined, well researched questions.  **[help]** [*how do I ask a good question?*](http://sound.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 2):

Each of those numbers is the main frequency that you can change the volume of. You need practice (with your ear) to figure out what freq does what in your case, you just need to know that you only change frequency levels and nothing more (for start, Ι assume that if you don't know what those numbers are, you probably don't try nothing more complicated). You can (theoretically) get rid of background sound by cutting all useless background frequencies, but it can be difficult without change (or even distort) sounds you might want not to. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Right. Actually it's impossible to really _get rid of_ background noise with only a 5-band graphical EQ. To do that, you need at least a parametric EQ, more likely a full STDFT tool like iZotope RX or Algorithmix reNOVAtor, which correspond to an equaliser with _thousands_ of bands whose settings continuously change in time!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds like an graphic equalizer, similar to this: [image: Equalizer from Commons][1]: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Graphic_equalizer.jpg

These are used to adjust the signal strength of specific frequencies to limits of +/- 6 or 12 dB per frequency. If you move the bar labeled 910 to the bottom it means that you have reduced an area focused on the frequency 910hz by either 6 or 12 dB, depending on what the EQ says. If you move it to the top, you have increased the signal in the same frequency by a similar amount.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to ask such a question in such a fashion you have neither the skill or inclination to do what you want to do. It sounds like your describing a graphic equaliser which is not what such a device is used for, you need a parametric eq. Furthermore to reduce background noise requires restoration software like izotope RX5 if you want to remove all of it.
My advice is to hand it over to someone who can do it for you. Sorry if I sound abrasive but audio engineering of any kind is a seriously under appreciated skill. But by all means if you want to learn then read some books and self study and in about 20 years you can come here a give advice of your own.